# Trying to get the exact grep property to give the results which contain the whole sentence

Tags: linux

I have a criteira, where I have the below property name in a file which needs to be modified only when the user give the exact name as in the file.
hello.busy.world=23

## "hello.busy.world"

User should be allowed to give the entire name "hello.busy.world"

In case if user give "busy", my script will actually not allow the user to move forward unless he gives the complete name

> I was trying to give something like below:
>
> > grep -w '$input' /usr/mware/example.properties|wc -l
> >     1
>
> If the user gives "busy", the above gives 1, my script will allow the user to go ahead and modify the value of the property name.
>
> But I am looking for a grep parameter, where it should give 0, unless the user gives the complete word "hello.busy.world"

```
a=`grep -w '$input' /usr/mware/example.properties|wc -l`
if [ $a -eq 1 ]
then
modfify the example.properties
else
break
fi
```

Please help in giving the exact grep property, which should give 0 results if the input does not match the complete property in the file

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question. It doesn't seem to make any sense at the moment (to me at least). Are you looking to grep exact matches, not just substrings?

Comment: You might need something like `grep ^$input=`? The `^` is the "beginning of line"/

Comment: You have the up arrow for saying thank you! Don't forget to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent matching a substring, you have to specify what determines "the beginning" of your potential search target. In your case it is `^`, i.e. the beginning of the line: `grep ^$input=`